# Is there a way to do embarrassingly parallel run of a program for multi gpu environment in python?

Tags: multiprocessing, gpu

I have a node with 4 GPU's attached. I have a python code which consists of a loop that can be embarrassingly parallelized. Currently my program only uses 1 GPU (I use a library which runs the does simulations on GPU and does not support multi GPU). Is there a way in python to run my code on multiple GPU's? I want something analogous to below but for GPUs

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def func(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(5) as p:
        print(p.map(func, [1, 2, 3]))
```

Answer (score 1):

I was also was interested in this and tested it. The following code snippet works for me.

```py
import os
import time
import ray

ray.init(num_gpus=2)

@ray.remote(num_gpus=0.25)
def func(x):
    print(x * x)

#The eight tasks created here can execute concurrently on two GPUs
ray.get([func.remote(i) for i in range(8)])
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest giving Ray a try. See [GPU support](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/using-ray-with-gpus.html?highlight=gpu). You can basically use `@ray.remote(num_gpus=1)` to annotate `func(x)` invoke it with `func.remote(1)`.